# How to apply on subdivision modifier in 2.91

Tags: modifiers, vertices, sculpting, subdivision-surface

The 'apply' and 'copy' buttons are not available inside the subdivision modifier on the latest blender 2.91.0.  I am not understanding that from where can I access it.
I started off with a very blocky object and smoothed it out but it is very jagged for sculpting small details and I don't know why but the subdivide is not working.

Answer (score 3):

Those options have been condensed into this dropdown menu.

[image]